# VSTFS 2015 - Merge Pull request set no-ff

Tags: git, tfs, git-flow, fast-forward

I'm using a VS-TFS 2015 to manage my project and I've enabled pull-request and using branch policies.

For manage the pull-request, I want that merges to develop branch (there is a Git Repo ahead) are done with no-ff option.
In the MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/vsts/git/branch-policies#enforce-a-merge-strategy), there is a "Enforce a merge strategy" section but that does not appear in my TFS-2015 Dashboard.

Any ideas to enable that or a workaround ? I supose that no-ff is not activated by default when we validate a merge pull-request ?

Comment: Daniel is right, it's not available in TFS 2015. Seems the only way is upgrading to a newer version of TFS (2017 or later) if you want to use the no-ff policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to a newer version of TFS. Merge strategies were not available in TFS 2015.